# Changing language dont "trigger" resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been spending a few hours now, looking through stackoverflow and I cant find an answer that fix my proble.

I'm trying to add multiple language support for the website and this is the code I have.

```
<a class="heading-line" href="/">@ISmile.Resources.HomeText.Home</a>
<a class="heading-line" href="/shop">@ISmile.Resources.HomeText.All_brands</a>
```

My **Resource files** are named `HomeText.resx` and `HomeText.dk.resx`

So far they contain this:

```
Name     -     Value
Home           Home
All_brands     AllBrands
```

Same for `HomeText.dk.resx` but ofc the Value fields in danish.

When I click in my drop down and select a language it triggers an action in my controller.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left select_Language" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/Language/Change/?LanguageAbbrevation=en&returnurl=@Request.Url"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span> ENG</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li-last">
        <a href="/Language/Change/?LanguageAbbrevation=dk&returnurl=@Request.Url"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dk"></span> DK</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Language Controller**

```
public ActionResult Change(string LanguageAbbrevation, string returnurl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LanguageAbbrevation))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
        }

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return Redirect(returnurl);

    }
```

And finally my `Application_BeginRequest` In **Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
            }
        }
```

When I debug and change the language, it set the cookie to the correct value (either dk or en) but it never change the Resource value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the `LanguageAbbrevation=dk` to `LanguageAbbrevation=da-DK` And also rename your  `HomeText.dk.resx` to `HomeText.da-DK.resx`